# Recursive function that prints every second number from n to 0 minimum. What am I missing?

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
def nr(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if n >= 1:
            return nr(n-2)

a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
print(nr(a))
```

Comment: You are never returning anything greater than 0. You're only looping through `nr` till you reach 0 and then retun 0. Or you reach 1 and do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> prints every second number

There's only one `print` statement. You should print inside the recursive function to `print` multiple times:

```
def nr(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    else:
        if n >= 1:
            print(n)
            nr(n - 2)

a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
nr(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some issues identified are:

- Given any odd number, your code returns `None` since n becomes -1 which is not considered.
- You are not returning the list of numbers you want, you are returning only the last number.

The following code should work. I believe you need the list for further processing rather than just printing them. So returning the required numbers as a list

```
def nr(n, list):
    if n == 0:
        list.append(n)
        return list
    elif n >= 1:
            list.append(n)
            return nr(n - 2,list)
    else:
        return list

a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
list = []
list = nr(a, list)
print(list)
```

Answer (score -1):

if n == 1, then n-2 == -1, which skips your base case. You can remove the if-else entirely and simply have the function terminate once n is less than 0. Finally, you want your print statement within the function so that it is called every iteration.

```
def nr(n):
    if n >= 0:
        print(n)
        return nr(n-2)

a = int(input('Enter a number: '))
nr(a)
```

Comment: you seem to have enough points to be able to post the comment

Comment: I don't know what that means